# Elasticsearch start error:Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started

Tags: elasticsearch, centos7

When I install elasticsearch on my virtual machine, elasticsearch does not start properly.

I tried to do these:
vi /etc/security/limits.conf

- soft nofile 65536
- hard nofile 131072
- soft nproc 2048
- hard nproc 4096

vi /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf

- soft nproc 4096

vi /etc/sysctl.conf 
vm.max_map_count=655360

```sh
[es@test elasticsearch-7.3.1]$ ./bin/elasticsearch
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[2019-09-10T22:52:12,836][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [test] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [35.4gb], net total_space [39.9gb], types [rootfs]
[2019-09-10T22:52:12,850][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [test] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2019-09-10T22:52:12,856][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] node name [test], node ID [G5dWJVSFTOWAVpNseEPcsQ], cluster name [elasticsearch]
[2019-09-10T22:52:12,857][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] version[7.3.1], pid[19178], build[default/tar/4749ba6/2019-08-19T20:19:25.651794Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.4/11.0.4+10-LTS]
[2019-09-10T22:52:12,859][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] JVM home [/opt/jdk-11.0.4]
[2019-09-10T22:52:12,859][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-3827173686900523231, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Dio.netty.allocator.type=unpooled, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=536870912, -Des.path.home=/usr/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.3.1, -Des.path.conf=/usr/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.3.1/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,967][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,977][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,978][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [data-frame]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,979][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [flattened]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,979][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,980][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,981][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,981][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,982][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,983][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,984][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,984][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [parent-join]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [percolator]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,986][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,986][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [reindex]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,987][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [repository-url]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,987][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,988][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [vectors]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,988][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,989][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,989][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,990][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,990][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,991][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,991][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,992][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,992][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,993][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,993][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,994][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,994][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2019-09-10T22:52:23,995][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [test] no plugins loaded
[2019-09-10T22:52:48,793][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [test] parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.3.1/config/roles.yml]
[2019-09-10T22:52:51,610][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [test] [controller/19279] [Main.cc@110] controller (64 bit): Version 7.3.1 (Build 1d93901e09ef43) Copyright (c) 2019 Elasticsearch BV
[2019-09-10T22:52:53,219][DEBUG][o.e.a.ActionModule       ] [test] Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security
[2019-09-10T22:52:55,389][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [test] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2019-09-10T22:53:03,862][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] initialized
[2019-09-10T22:53:03,886][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] starting ...
[2019-09-10T22:53:05,370][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [test] publish_address {10.1.2.91:9301}, bound_addresses {[::]:9301}
[2019-09-10T22:53:05,397][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [test] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
[2019-09-10T22:53:05,451][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] stopping ...
[2019-09-10T22:53:05,531][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] stopped
[2019-09-10T22:53:05,531][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] closing ...
[2019-09-10T22:53:05,588][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [test] closed
[2019-09-10T22:53:05,593][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.NativeController] [test] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
```

I want it to start normally, but it always shows this error: [2019-09-10T22:53:05,593][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.NativeController] [test] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started`enter code here`

Answer (score 10):

Here is the problem :
[max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

That work for me :

```
 sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=280530
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to this error:

```
[2019-09-10T22:53:05,397][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [test] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
```

see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/discovery-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

May be specifying these three things correctly may solve your error trace.

`1)` Change the `network.host` in elastic configuration (elasticsearch.yml), look for the line containing network.host and uncomment it and set it to 0.0.0.0.

`2)` Change the JVM options, if you are using a zip file locate `jvm.options` in the config/ folder.

`3)` Set `discovery.seed_hosts:` also if any error still persists.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/jvm-options.html

Comment: @uoiea Also found you have changed the custom port of 9200/9300 of ES. Please make sure you have done it correctly.